# Ionic2 footer toolbar text doesn't take up full width on IOS

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I have a footer toolbar on my ionic2 app that has a center-aligned text, but the text only seems to take the center 50% or so of the width of the toolbar and then cuts off with an ellipses (see image). The width seems to correspond to the same width of the text allowed for the header toolbar (which I've grayed out in the image). Is there a way to override this and make the text take up the full space? So far I've only noticed this issue on an iPhone 6, although I haven't tried that many devices.

[image]

```
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
   <ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="mySelectedIndex">
     tabs omitted..
   </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar color="{{threatLevelColor}}">
    <ion-title *ngIf="threatLevel" text-center>
      Security Threat Level: {{threatLevel.level}}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Can you show your `html`?

Comment: Sorry, added to original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply below `SCSS` change only for `iOS` platform.

**.scss**

```
.ios,
{
    your-page {
        .padding-0 {
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**.html**

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar color="{{threatLevelColor}}">
    <ion-title *ngIf="threatLevel" text-center class="padding-0">
      Security Threat Level: {{threatLevel.level}}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```